# PayPal Express: is checkout.js required?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I need to implement PayPal with PHP and read their (opaque) docs and a lot of tutorials and YouTube videos.

But what I don't understand: is the checkout.js required? 
I can't find any tutorial using the checkout.js … none is utilising this script, all are just PHP.
Most popular links are https://www.sanwebe.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php or http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-integrate-your-website-with-paypal-using-php/

More confusing is, that I don't know is PayPal Express === checkout.js? Because I have seen other scripts calling functions like doExpressCheckout() … so I think you can use PP Express without the checkout.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not required, but it's the recommended integration. Checkout.js will take care of rendering the PayPal button and keeping the buyer on the same page while they check out.

Comment: Thanks bluepnume. I am currently working on my none-JS version, but will try to wrap my head around the documentation. If anybody has a good (complete) example or tutorial, that would be great!